The value of supinf when infsup is infinity
I have an optimization problem of the form:
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize } f(x) \text{ s.t. } x \in X \text{ and } g(x) \le G.
\end{align*}
I have $f$ and $g$ as continuous and convex functions on $X$, $X$ is both compact and convex, and $G \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $n > 1$. If there is no feasible $x$, I know that
\begin{align*}
\inf_{x\in X} \sup_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lambda \ge 0} \left[ f(x) + \langle\lambda, g(x) - G\rangle \right]= \infty.
\end{align*}
I am wondering if it is true that the supinf will be infinity as well, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
\sup_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lambda \ge 0}\inf_{x\in X} \left[ f(x) + \langle\lambda, g(x)-G\rangle \right]= \infty.
\end{align*}
When $n=1$, it is easy to show as we can let $\lambda$ grow unbounded on the real line but in the case when $n>1$, I am not sure how to construct a sequence of $\lambda$s that can take the infimum value go to infinity.

If the < and > in $<\lambda, g(x)-G>$ are meant to be angle brackets, then use \langle and \rangle, $\langle \lambda, g(x)-G\rangle$.
